# codaSlider hack - how do I add little triangles overlaying an image

Tags: jquery, css, coda-slider

Check out [CodaSlider](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html).

I've removed the UL and opted for div's to control it but i'm running into a problem. I want to add a triangle signifying which panel its currently displaying. At the moment, I'm thinking of adding the triangle to the actual slide.jpg, but this is quite bad if someone wants to add another slide.

How would you go about adding a triangle to the current panel dynamically?

Like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5gCB.jpg (It's added on the image)

My CSS:

```
#control {

width: 938px;
height: 65px;
border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
background: #fff url(sliderbg.jpg) repeat;

}

.button { float: left; width: 220px; height: 65px;
margin-right: 15px; border-right: 1px dotted  #d1d1d1; }

.buttonInside { padding: 8px; }

.buttonLast { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 2px; border-right: 0px;}
```

Solution:

Include

```
ul.navigation a.selected {
background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat top center;
position: relative;
top: -13px;
padding-top: 23px;
```

}

Set floating element as inline elements can't be given widths and heights

```
ul.navigation li {
float: left;
margin-right: 12px;
width: 220px;
height: 65px;
border-right: 1px dotted #ddd;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a pseudoelement and CSS to add an arrow without an image: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/fqKHK/

The CSS with the stock CodaSlider would look like:

```
ul.navigation a.selected {
  position: relative;

  background: blue;

  color: #FFF;
}
ul.navigation a.selected:before {
  content: '';

  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  bottom: -9px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  z-index: 1;

  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Browser support is modern browsers and IE8+. For IE 7 and lower, I would use an image as @Marco advises or just plain not worry about it.

**UPDATE:**

I had some time, so I played a bit more with your specific implementation.

Just to clarify, you need help getting the javascript to work with your changes in markup in addition to getting a "current slide" arrow.

Take a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/SfJzv/

**Make note of these changes:**

In the HTML, I added the `.navigation` class to your `#control` element. This will help keep your markup working with the CodaSlider script.

In the javascript: on line 34 of the script (referencing this script: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.js), changed `.parents('ul:first')` to `.parents('.navigation:first')`, and on line 53 changed `$('ul.navigation a:first').click();` to `$('div.navigation a:first').click();`.

In the CSS I made some style declarations to override some of the stock CodaSlider CSS to work with your dimensions. You may or may not need this depending on your implementation.

Here's a full screen demo: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/SfJzv/embedded/result/

Comment: This looks great but it wasn't really my question.. I wanted to add a active arrow in my example screenshot above .button overlaying the content in my panels :)

Comment: How is this not adding an active arrow overlaying the panel content? Did you look at the jsFiddle? Granted I'm not using your classes, but I don't have the context of your HTML to really understand them.

Comment: Well I did mentin that I wasn't using UL, instead using a div class for each button.. + I can't see the CSS that's making the arrow :(

Comment: @SMacFadyen Yeah, but the classes aren't even the same. So I just pulled in CodaSlider's resources to get a working model up. What browser are you using?

Comment: @SMacFadyen Here's a screenshot of how it should look: http://cl.ly/AwKM I'm very curious about what browser your using.

Comment: Browser? Firefox 7. It does work. I just want a arrow above .class when active. The codaslider JS is selecting ul a's and stuff though ;/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4266/discussion-between-brent-and-smacfadyen)

Comment: I managed to do the same myself, but thanks alot for your time - I might still implement yours if it's more efficient!

Comment: How would it be possible to add on this and reverse the direction of the arrow so that it is facing upwards above the bottom border?

What I really need is the arrow in this http://jsfiddle.net/Sycren/dfTtm/2/ to be reversed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it on the button instead of the image.

I can see you got an buttonInside.

So you could add an active state to the ACTIVE imagebutton, and then have

```
.active .buttonInside {margin-top:-20px; background:url(arrow.png) top center; padding-top:28px;}
```

or something like that :)

Comment: Would this overlay above my button then? No need for setting extra height?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ShowHide(obj) {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("div3").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("div4").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(obj).style.display = 'inline';


        return false;
    }
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
    a
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: Transparent;
        top: 0;
        vertical-align: text-top;
    }
</style>
```

---

Body

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p>
        Hope this works</p>
    <div style="width: 938px; height: 100px; z-index: -1; border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
        border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1; position: absolute;
        left: 8px; top: 20px; z-index: -1; background-color: Black">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 75px; z-index: 99; background-color: Red; height: 35px; width: 940px">
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 35px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
            <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 35px; background-color: Blue; text-align: center;">
                <div id="div1" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: Black; position: absolute;
                    margin-left: 5%;">
                </div>
                <a onclick="ShowHide('div1');">ClickMe1</a>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 35px; background-color: Aqua; text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle">
                <div id="div2" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: Black; position: absolute;
                    margin-left: 5%; display: none">
                </div>
                <a onclick="ShowHide('div2');">ClickMe1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 35px">
            <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 35px; background-color: Fuchsia; text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle">
                <div id="div3" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: Black; position: absolute;
                    margin-left: 5%; display: none">
                </div>
                <a onclick="ShowHide('div3');">ClickMe1</a>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 35px; background-color: Green; text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle">
                <div id="div4" style="height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: Black; position: absolute;
                    margin-left: 5%; display: none">
                </div>
                <a onclick="ShowHide('div4');">ClickMe1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Hope this works..... u can place ur image in side the div(div1, div2, div3, div4). And sorry the code need a lil cleaning up. :)